# What's the difference between a simple chat room and a gallery chat room?

Tags: support, chat, privileges

There are two different privileges to [Create chat rooms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat-rooms) and to [Create gallery chat rooms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms).

- What's difference between these two different types of chat rooms?
- Can a simple chat room be converted into a gallery chat room?

Comment: @Bart: Is there any differentiation to identify chat room is gallery chat room or not? Does simple chat room is only based on invite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first question is simply answered by your second link (emphasis mine)

> "Chat rooms are typically public and open to all. A gallery chat room
>   allows anyone to enter, but **only specific users may talk** in the room,
>   as determined by the room owner."

You can identify whether or not a chat room is a gallery chat room by a small lock icon in the upper left hand corner such as indicated below.

[image]

Moderators and chat room owners are able to change the chat room type.

Comment: Mods can change room types, btw

Comment: You crazy mods and your priviliges. Mod-only option then?

Comment: @Sathya: Does room owner can't change room type? If yes, how? If No, why?

Comment: I believe room owners can also flip the switch from the access tab of Room info screen // @SomnathMuluk

Comment: @Sathya: Yes. I got location. In access tab of info of chat room, there is option for changing room to gallery room.