# Why have my privileges on Stack Overflow changed?

Tags: support, review, privileges

On Stack Overflow, I have a reputation of 189 and I used to have the ability to review posts. On Stack Overflow chat, I had no restrictions on chatting.

Now, suddenly, the "Review" option has disappeared, and in chat, most rooms seem to be locked.

Nothing appears to have changed on my SO profile, and I received no notifications of any sort that my rights were somehow being limited.

Has there been changes to SO policies/levels? If so, what were those changes? If there hasn't been any change to SO policies, then what gives with my account?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

Comment: 2013-07-26: The reputation requirement to access the First Posts and Late Answers queue was bumped up to [fill the empty 500 reputation privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark) (from [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange))

Comment: So the reputation required has been modified. I was granted the review right at 150 Rep...but now it has been upped to 500.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "most rooms seem to be locked."

Comment: If you look at this screenshot http://d.pr/i/bo9I you will see that most rooms have a lock icon and a diamond next to them. For example, I logged into the javascript room and there was a message at the bottom that said "Only users nominated can talk here". I opened a chat room with one of the owners of the room, and he messaged me with @alisamii in the Javascript room and I was able to chat again.

Comment: I think they are galary chat room.

Comment: [What's the difference between a simple chat room and a gallery chat room?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142832)

Answer (score 1):

> Has there been changes to SO policies/levels ?

Yes, the privileges for review has been transfer from 125 reputation to minimun 500 reputation on Stack Overflow.

Two reviews **Late Answers** & **First Posts** can be possible only once you crossed 500 reputation.

For more information you can visit [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).

Regarding the chat room locked, whenever any chat room has `lock` icon that chat room is in galary mode and you require to grant access to talk in to that chat room. Room owner can grant to this access.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...so, users previously granted the priviledge have been stripped of that priviledge. That is too bad. But as for my chat priviledges...why are many of the rooms now locked?

Comment: which specific room you are talking about ?

Comment: Many, for example, Javascript for one. @OctavianDamiean confirmed that the room is not in gallery mode, so I am unsure why I was locked out until he messaged me directly in the room.

Comment: @alisamii does it shows lock icon near diamond icon ?

Comment: @alisamii [Java script](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/17/javascript?tab=access) chat room in in galary mode

Comment: yes, it does...